# Given distances from an external point to 2 points on a circle and its center, what is the radius of the circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

From a point outside a circle, I know the distance to two (or more if needed) points along the circle, as well as the distance to the center of the circle.  Angles are unknown.  How can I calculate the radius (or distance between the two points)?

[image]

From the image, a, b, and x are known. I also have measurements to more points along the circle if needed, say c and d.

Comment: Along the distances $a$ and $b$, do you have any angle? Or distance between the two points on the circle? Without further information, it's impossible to know the radius: the two points may be anywhere on the circle, that only provides a lower bound and an upper bound for the radius.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut no, unfortunately not. I had feared it was not possible to calculate without more information.  Dang!

Comment: There's not enough information, no matter how many distances you provide. Consider: If there are points with those distances on a particular circle, then there are just as many points with those distances on a slightly-larger circle, or even on a line between your point and the "center".

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the question come from?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut a video game, actually. The context is it's a space game with large celestial bodies with POIs scattered across them. I'm writing a "routing" program of sorts, to determine shortest possible routes, etc. To do so, I basically need to form a Cartesian coordinate system identifying the POIs' locations along the surface of a sphere (planet/moon).

We aren't given coordinates, so the only I thing I have to work with are reference distances. Fortunately, I was able to retrieve the radius, but now I face the problem of calculating all the coordinates from reference distances.

Comment: Well, same problem: with the distance, you know circles were the POI lie, but you can't know their coordinates. Unless you can know distances from another known point (you can then do a kind of [triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation)).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut This image sort of defines the problem as it now stands. All variables/coordinates are known except A (x, y, z).  Points 1-4 are reference points outside the circle, and in a 3D space I have Points 5 and 6 directly above and below the sphere.  All points are equidistant to their adjacent neighbors.


[link](https://i.imgur.com/s7aeprO.png)

Comment: Ah, then it's much better. You have a pyramid with all known distances, hence you can indeed compute the coordinates of $A$. Even with only three points $P_1,P_2,P_3$ it would be possible (you have a tatrahedron). However the formula will probably not be nice. You should post this as another question.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, I'm thinking I will! I'm good at the programming part, not so much the geometry/trig part after being out of school for many, many years.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Geometrically, one point with distance defines a sphere, two points yield the intersection of two spheres, hence a circle, and with a third point you know on which point of the circle is $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have measurements to more points like point $Y$ then the radius is: $R=Y-X$
[image]

Comment: I do have measurements to more points, but I cannot be certain that any of those points lie on a line intersecting the center of the circle and my external reference point.